# Check if cuboids are overlapping as fast as possible (no iteration) in c++

Tags: c++, intersection

I have a cuboid class where cuboid coordinates are provided as set of arrays:

```
Cuboid3D cube_a      ({1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f}, // x coordinates
                    {2.0f, 4.0f, 3.0f, 7.0f, 2.0f, 9.0f, 5.0f, 2.0f}, // y coordinates
                   {1.0f, 3.0f, 6.0f, 9.0f, 4.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f, 7.0f}); // z coordinates

  Cuboid3D cube_b      ({3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f}, // x coordinates
                    {1.0f, 3.0f, 5.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f}, // y coordinates
                   {1.0f, 3.0f, 6.0f, 9.0f, 4.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f, 7.0f}); // z coordinates
```

I need to find the fastest way to get true/false result if cubes are intersected in any point. Problem is how to implement this without iteration, i.e. how to compare the points - how to get max min from arrays without iteration. I need this to work as fast as possible as it will be used many times.

It should be something similar to the method which checks if "cuboids" are identical:

```
 bool
Rectangle3D::operator==(const Rectangle3D& other) const
{
    if (!std::equal(_x_coords.begin(), _x_coords.end(), other._x_coords.begin(), other._x_coords.end(),
                    [&] (const auto &rhs, const auto &lhs) {return std::fabs(rhs - lhs) < 1.0e-13;})) return false;

    if (!std::equal(_y_coords.begin(), _y_coords.end(), other._y_coords.begin(), other._y_coords.end(),
                    [&] (const auto &rhs, const auto &lhs) {return std::fabs(rhs - lhs) < 1.0e-13;})) return false;

    if (!std::equal(_z_coords.begin(), _z_coords.end(), other._z_coords.begin(), other._z_coords.end(),
                    [&] (const auto &rhs, const auto &lhs) {return std::fabs(rhs - lhs) < 1.0e-13;})) return false;

    return true;
}
```

So in a similar way, how to check - or start checking - if my shapes intersect at any given point and as soon as they do give outcome immediately?

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit. What max and min do you want from what array? Where do you think to need iteration?

Comment: It sounds like your "cuboids" are axis aligned cubes, correct? (Otherwise the intersecion code you provided doesn't make sense.) Why can't you just define them as such - instead of storing 8*3=24 floating point coordinates, just store 6 floating point values: the min&max value for each axis? Also, std::max https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max has a variation that you can use like so: `std::max({1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f})`. But if you just have an array of unordered values, you will still have to look at each of them to get the min/max, whether you are using iteration or not.

Comment: Looking at the values for the vertexes in your example, your "cubeoids" are far from axis aligned, though. Figuring out if they intersect (not just their axis-aligned bounding boxes) will be much more complicated than finding the min/max of their coordinates.

Comment: From your comments I see that I have this problem even deeper that I thought. Cuboids can be very varied and are not axis aligned cubes, so it seems that my intersection code is not valid. How can I get min/max of the array without iteration?

Comment: `std::max({1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f})` ?

Comment: I have updated the question and provided the comparison function which should be smth very similar what I am looking for intersection

Comment: I have the impression your question is very unclear: you mention cuboids and Rectangle3D (which consist of not less than six rectangles), but when drawing the points you mention, I don't even see one rectangle (maybe I'm mistaking here but I don't see any). So it looks like your figures are not cuboids, but other 3D figures. In that case the sequence there are connected might be important. Are you looking for "real" intersections of possible ones? Please update the question with some drawing in order to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get a min and max. This operations will take at least O(n) time. This only can change if you have specific prerequisites for you data. So you know e.g. the min value can only be one of 2 vertexes. Or the data is sorted in some sense.

From what I read you don't have anything like this. You just get 2 arbitrary cuboids. So you have to look at every coordinate at least once to find a min or max value. Depending on what you do you can store these values and see if you can reuse them. If e.g. you have to compare one cuboid to many others.

In general you have 24 values per cuboid and to find e.g. minX you have to iterate over 8 values. In my short test I needed 92 nanoseconds for this (and even on weaker hardware I doubt that this will take longer than a microsecond). So ask yourself the question what are you actual runtime requirements. Do you really need to optimize for nanoseconds? This really smells like premature optimization to me.

Judging from the complexity of the problem I would focus on actually solving the task first. This is not trivial and can be implemented in multiple ways. Think about such minor optimizations later if you really need to.

Some links I was able to find regarding the overlap check of cuboids:
 https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130408/what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-check-if-two-cubes-intersect-where-the-cubes-a

https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question and provided the comparison function which should be smth very similar what I am looking for intersection

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do, is to verify if your "cuboid" is indeed a cuboid: I've drawn your first "cuboid" in a graphical tool (geogebra) and this does not look like a valid cuboid to me (in case I'm mistaking, please give me four points who make a rectangle, the four others should then make a rectangle a bit further).

I see there is some discussion whether or not you want to be working with axis parallel cuboids or not. I would use this in order to define your cuboid, let's say you do the following:

- Take one point in space, and make this the center of your cuboid.
- Take three floating point numbers, which define the sizes of your cuboid.
- (this part might be optional) in case you define your cuboid as not parallel to the axis, define two floating point numbers (from 0 to 2*Pi), which define the angles against the axes.

This will give you a better definition of your cuboids instead of eight random numbers, and you can start from there (e.g. by comparing the centre coordinates and the sizes) to calculate possible intersections.

Comment: I have updated the question and provided the comparison function which should be smth very similar what I am looking for intersection